# Transfer email data from one HTML file to another being displayed with "%40" instead of "@"

Tags: javascript, php, forms, href

I plan to use the sign-in input box as a email input, and I need it to be displayed on page 2 ( password.php ) this is where the user will input their password but above the box I wish to display their email, so I need whatever is inputted into first page onto second, I have tried with this way and it works but the "@" symbol is displayed as "%40", so the email will be displayed on page 2 something like "myemail%40gmail.com", can someone help me please?

**sign-in.php**

```
            <html>
            <head>
               <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="asd.js"></script>
            </head>

            <body>

            <form name="form1" action="password.php" method="get">
            name:<input type ="text" id="name" name="n">
            <input type="submit" value="next" >
            <button type="button" id="print" onClick="testJS()"> Print </button>
            </form>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                
                function testJS() {
                var b = document.getElementById('name').value,
                    url = '/AMAZON-LATEST_ngreatest/new/password.php?name=' + encodeURIComponent(b);

                document.location.href = url;
            }
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

**password.php**

```
            <form name="form1" action="password.php" method="get">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td id="here">test</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.onload = function () {
                var url = document.location.href,
                    params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'),
                    data = {}, tmp;
                for (var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++) {
                     tmp = params[i].split('=');
                     data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
                }
                document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = data.name;
            }
            </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you using this:

```js
    console.log(decodeURIComponent('any%40%3Fgmail.com'))
```